# Software that can actually screen scrape bot OCR

Tags: windows, linux, scraping, copy-paste

I wanted some recommendations on software for both Linux and Windows that can actually screen scrape and not OCR.

Screen Scrape -> OCR are generally not accurate even with trained models. I wanted some automated programmable solution that can scrape text that is being rendered at monitor screen. I don't know how computer displays work. But whether we are displaying typed text or rendering structured files like pdf or html webpages their must be some process that instructs computer monitor to display the text alphabets to render on pixels.
Isn't is possible to capture text from those processes like raw dump screen text into file?

On unix terminals, a tweak would be to dump vcs tty content to file.

But I am talking about GUI elements displays.

Cant we scrape GUI screen content directly by dumping the text that was raw processed by monitors.

E.g. How copy paste works. When we select text on screen and copy it doesn't perform OCR it was literally dumping text to clipboard.

Is there some software specially programmable or with CLI?

Comment: Screens are sent a graphical image to display. The do not receive high level gui commands.